# How to write an extension method in C# with multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, extension-methods

I write this extension method but I get only one param.

My C# code:

```
public static string ToEncrypt(this string key, string passWord)
{
    // Salt and IV is randomly generated each time, but is prepended to encrypted cipher text
    // so that the same Salt and IV values can be used when decrypting.  
    var saltStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
    var ivStringBytes = Generate256BitsOfRandomEntropy();
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    using (var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passWord, saltStringBytes, DerivationIterations))
    {
        var keyBytes = password.GetBytes(Keysize / 8);

        using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivStringBytes))
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        // Create the final bytes as a concatenation of the random salt bytes, the random iv bytes and the cipher bytes.
                        var cipherTextBytes = saltStringBytes;
                        cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(ivStringBytes).ToArray();
                        cipherTextBytes = cipherTextBytes.Concat(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToArray();
                        memoryStream.Close();
                        cryptoStream.Close();

                        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I try to use this extension method:

[CallBack Miss Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjATF.png)

[image]

I've searched in google but could not find a solution to my problem.

Thanks you all! Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. The extension method is a method that receives, on its own, at least one parameter. The type of this first parameter is the type which will have this method as if it was in the original class. So as your method has two parameters, when calling as an extension method, it will have one: the passWord. So what is your question?

Comment: Yep, as @Andrew says, think of the first parameter as being the object on which the extension method is called. You probably want to switch the order of key and password in your method declaration.

Comment: I agree with @Ben, I think that's your issue. BTW, your method should be probably be called `Encrypt`, or maybe `ToEncrypted`. And I **highly** discourage having two variables so similarly named: `password` and `passWord`.

Comment: If this is for storing user passwords, you should _hash_ them, not _encrypt_ them. You should never be able to reverse your user's passwords into plaintext. You should compare the hash of the password the user enters with the hash stored in the database. If this is for user passwords, please research about the best methods for storing passwords.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are trying to write a extension method to encrypt the password with a key. 
So you function header should be:

```
public static string ToEncrypt(this string passWord, string key)
```

Later you can use this extension like below:

```
string encrpted = password.ToEncrypt("your key here");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your extension method is written for the string it’s acting upon to be the “key” and not the “password”

So your code, as it’s written, should be

```
var key = “some key”;
var encryptedpass = key.ToEncrypt(password);
```

Your code doesn’t even reference key but your extension method does.